# Problem with installing programs

Tags: 10.10, installation, zip

I am unable to install programs for the Ubuntu 10.10 system. The download is ok, but when attempting to install them, the following message is displayed,

```
AN ERROR OCCURRED WHILE OPENING THE ARCHIVE

END-OF-CENTRAL-DIRECTORY SIGNATURE NOT FOUND etc.......

ZIPINFO: CANNOT FIND ZIPFILE DIRECTORY IN etc......
```

As I am new to Ubuntu and also fairly "green" as far as computer terminology is concerned, I have no idea what this means and don't have a clue on how to fix it.

Can you help please?

Many thanks,
Brian Buck

Comment: What were you trying to install?

Comment: Could you give us some more inforamtion?Are you trying to install it from source?What program you were trying to install?

Comment: Was it just one program that did this, multiple? Where you using the software center, synaptic package manager, downloaded .deb file, compiling from source? More info and I'm sure one of us here can happily help you out.

Comment: What did you precisely do to get this error ?

Comment: Please give us the complete output of `sudo apt-get install packageOfYourChoiceGoesHere`. Thanks.

Comment: I have attempted to install a variety of programs including Picasa, Incredimail, Google Earth, Worldwide Telescope etc, and also attempted to install a few other programs from disks - all result in the same message appearing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to run `unzip` or double click on a `.zip` or `.msi`. file.  You probably downloaded a program for Windows.

Linux programs are usually distributed as `.deb` files, or sometimes `.rpm`, `.bin`, or `.tar.gz`.

Try to find a `.deb` file, then you can just double click on it to install it.

In the case of WorldWide Telescope, it looks like you need the "Web Client" version.

Follow [the instructions here](http://www.worldwidetelescope.org/webclient/) to install Moonlight and then the appropriate browser extension.

Or if you **really** need to run a Windows version, read about [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: @Brian Buck Did it work? If so, mark this as the answer!